# Redirect to /user upon login

Tags: users, redirection

I can't figure out why users are redirected to http://example.org/user (the domain is just an example) when they log in. I don't see a rule anywhere. I have written rules to redirect somewhere else upon login, and the rules do not work. I suspect the Logintoboggan or the Drupal Commerce, but I can't find any settings that would cause this. I don't have any other redirect modules installed.

Why are user redirected to their user profile after they log in?

Comment: You don't specify Drupal 7 or 8, but assuming 7 have you looked at [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination)??

Comment: Bleen's answer is probably good but I have not tried it This can certainly be achieved with https://www.drupal.org/project/rules React on event "user: user has logged in"
and add Action "System: Page Redirect"

Comment: The OP is not asking what to use to redirect users, but why users are redirect to http://example.org/user (the domain is just an example).

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is specified in the login form forst_state array under the redirect key, that's why. You can change that by altering the user login form.